# Compartilhar textos iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Como eu faço para compartilhar um texto nas redes sociais em um App iOS em Swift 3? 
Tenho várias Frases aleatórias em um array e caso a pessoa goste de alguma gostaria de deixar a mesma compartilhar tal frase. Como ficaria o código de um botão para abrir opções entre compartilhar o texto atual no Facebook, WhatsApp, etc...

Como esse exemplo em Android na imagem abaixo:
[image: App de frases em Android]

Comment: Estou sem tempo de traduzir, mas veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35931947/2570426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo de como fazer isso com `Swift 3`

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // share text
    @IBAction func shareTextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // text to share
        let text = "This is some text that I want to share."

        // set up activity view controller
        let textToShare = [ text ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // share image
    @IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // image to share
        let image = UIImage(named: "Image")

        // set up activity view controller
        let imageToShare = [ image! ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931946/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Legal, era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado! Só mais uma coisa, como seria para compartilhar em outras redes, e-mail, etc., na teoria devo substituir isso "UIActivityType.postToFacebook", existem funções específicas como a postToFacebook?

Comment: Exatamente, o sistema vai te dar as opções disponíveis no seu iPhone. eé so não ter isso, pois é opcional. Se a resposta lhe ajudou, poderia marcar com resolvido.

Comment: adicionar UIActivityType a todos os elementos é redundante `[ .airDrop, .postToFacebook ]`